# Date sorting with SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

OBJECTIVE: Sort rows on website by date in ascending order. 
ISSUE: Dates are rendered in ascending order in chunks on webpage.

REASONING: Data fields are not set to the correct data type in the Db? Should I be using SQL to sort or PHP, or combo of both?

I attempted to use SQL: ORDER BY 'date' asc, however should I change the data types in the Db field? Currently set as tinytext. I took out my SQL in the script below...

//SCRIPT FOLLOWS

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <style/type = "text/css">

      table {
       background-color: #FCF;
       border-style:solid;
       border:5px solid red;
       }

      th {
      width: 150px;
      text-align: center;
      }

      td {
      text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
   </head>

 <body>
 <h1>San Antonio Triathlete Race Search</h1>

 [allowphp useadvancedfilter]

 DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'XXXXXX');
 DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', 'XXXXXX');
 DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'XXXXXX');
 DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'XXXXXX');

 $dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME);


 $where = '';
 if (isset($_POST['race'])) {
    $race = $POST['race'];
    $where = ' WHERE `'.$race."` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['criteria'])."'";
 }

 $query = 'SELECT * FROM `Races`'.$where;
 $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die('Cannot retrieve your request');
 $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows results found";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Race Date</th><th>Location</th><th>Event</th><th>Register</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC )) {

  $href = $row['Register'];

     echo "<tr><td>";
     echo $row['Date'];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['City'];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['Race Name'];
     echo "</td><td>";

  //if you echo with single quotes, it's easier to echo html tags:
  echo '<a href="http://'.$row['Register'].'" target="_blank">Register</a>';
  echo "</td></tr>";

 }

 echo "</table>";

 [/allowphp useadvancedfilter]

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What format are your dates in inside the `TINYTEXT` field? (ex: yyyy-mm-dd, m/d/y, etc)

Comment: can you tell me, what is the data type of column `date' in your table... `races`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski and@cyberboy I have no formatting set up I only have the tinytext type

Comment: @user3413142 The question is how do the dates look in the column? What kind of strings are they? Post a sample of what the dates look like - there are many ways to format them and we have no idea how you've formatted yours. (yyyy-mm-dd, yyyymmdd, mm/dd/yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy, Mon, dd, yyyy, etc...)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I see, my apologies. the format is mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

You should use the database to sort the results.  Your attempt:

```
ORDER BY 'date' asc
```

Doesn't sort because you are sorting by the constant string `'date'`.  Use backticks or nothing at all:

```
ORDER BY date asc
ORDER BY `date` asc
```

EDIT:

If your October dates are sorted first, then that is because you are storing the date as a string.  That is bad enough itself, but to call the field "date" is then even more misleading.

You need to use `str_to_date()`:

```
ORDER BY str_to_date(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

This will convert the string to a real date and order it correctly.

Comment: Nice fix with this however now my October dates are sorted before my March dates, which from an ASCII table makes sense...could this be due to using tinytext data type in the table rather than a data data type?

Comment: sorry, date data type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to make life simple the date fields should have proper data type date or datetime.

In addition I can see some issue with the code

```
$where = ' WHERE `'.$race."` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['criteria'])."'";
```

You are using `mysql_real_escape_string()` and this needs mysql connection where you are using the mysqli

so it should be as

```
$where = ' WHERE `'.$race."` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$_POST['criteria'])."'";
```